# Copying part of a matrix to another empty matrix with the same indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to copy part of a matrix (matrix 1) in **matlab** to another empty matrix of zeros (matrix 2) so that the section I copy from matrix 1 has the same indices in matrix 2, e.g.

Matrix 1 (mat1):

```
0 3 0 0 2 4 1 2 6
1 3 4 2 0 0 0 2 0 
0 2 6 1 3 6 6 1 1
0 0 0 2 1 3 3 1 0
1 4 5 2 3 3 0 0 1
```

Matrix 2 (mat2) *desired output*:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 4 2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 6 1 3 6 6 0 0
0 0 0 2 1 3 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've tried something like

```
mat2([2:4],[3:7]) = mat1([2:4],[3:7])
```

but of course it doesn't work... any ideas of an  efficient way to do this? I couldn't find another thread to help with this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does work.  You just need to create `mat2` first:

```
mat2 = zeros(size(mat1));
mat2(2:4, 3:7) = mat1(2:4, 3:7);
```

Note that you don't need the square brackets on those ranges.

Comment: Hi yes you're right it does work. I had also created the empty matrix first but made a stupid indexing mistake! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

`mat2 = zeros(size(mat1));`

Before copying over.